# Error trying to display information in my server using cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm working with cakephp. My cakephp version is v 0.2.9

I have a problem when wanting to display the module content BlackList. When I want to display it in my browser I have the following error message:

```
{"blacklist":"failed"}
```

I have my database connection, but I need to display information in blacklist when i write localhost/claro/getBlacklist.

I think that I have an error in the model or controller,I appreciate your help, thanks.

My Controller is:

```
public function getBlacklist() 
    {
        if(isset($this->params['url']["number"])) {
            $number = $this->params['url']["number"];
            $blacklist = $this->Blacklist->findNumber($number);
        } else {
            $blacklist = "failed";
        }

        $this->set('blacklist', $blacklist);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
```

Blacklist model is:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Blacklist extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Blacklist';



    public function findNumber($number) {
        $params = array(
                    'conditions' => array('number' => $number)
                    );


        $res = $this->find('first', $params);

        return $res;
    }


    public function getList() {
        $query = $this->find('all');

        return $query;
    }   


    public function addNumber($data) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO blacklists VALUE('', '" . $data["number"] . "')";
        $query = $this->query($sql);

        return $this->id;
    }

    public function vaciar() {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM blacklists where 1";
        $query = $this->query($sql);

        return 1;
    }

    public function deleteNumbers($info) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM blacklists WHERE id IN ($info)";
        $query = $this->query($sql);

        return 1;
    }

}

?>
```

And my AdminController is:

```
public function getBlack() {
        $black = $this->Blacklist->getList();
        $this->set('black', $black);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }


    public function addBlack() {
        if(isset($this->params['url']["number"])) {
            $badd = $this->Blacklist->addNumber($this->params['url']);
        } else {
            $badd = "failed";
        }

        $this->set('badd', $badd);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }

public function deleteBlack() {
        if(isset($this->params['url']["info"])) {
            $delblack = $this->Blacklist->deleteNumbers($this->params['url']["info"]);
        } else {
            $delblack = "failed";
        }

        $this->set('delblack', $delblack);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }

    public function vaciarBlack() {
        $bvaciar = $this->Blacklist->vaciar();
        $this->set('bvaciar', $bvaciar);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
```

Comment: Unless using an older version of cakePHP, then you should not be using `$this->params['url']["number"];` and instead should be using `$this->request->data['url']['number'];`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Actually it would be `$this->request->query['number']`

Comment: @user1974277 You'll have to at least show what your request looks like _exactly_ (URL, GET/POST data, etc...). Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: I still have the same problem :( @ndm

Comment: @ndm `query['key'];`? I use `data['key'];` in my projects, documentation supports that too. can you show a link? I'd hate to have been doing it wrong.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `CakeRequest::$data` is for accessing [PUT/POST data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data), it won't contain any [query string parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters).

Comment: @ndm Thanks. I think it was just a fundamental misunderstanding, I presumed he was POST'ing data, which is certainly wrong after re-reading. Thanks!

Comment: @user1974277 There is no CakePHP version `0.2.9`. Also again, what does your request to `getBlacklist` look like? Are you sure you are passing the expected query parameters?

Comment: @user1974277 wich one is the right version of your cakephp? there is a 0.2.9 version